# UIO driver - understanding implementation logic

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've started learning about UIO and DPDK and there's few gaps I don't understand and couldn't find a clear answer on the internet. I understand the buffers-offload, the CPU cache pollution offload and why the driver is generally faster.

But the user application and the UIO driver communicates through "files": (pseudo-filesystem, hugetlbfs)

- /dev/uioX
- /sys/class/uio/uioX/device/config
- /sys/class/uio/uioX/device/resourceX

1. Doesn't using read/write just generates a lot more context switches than using the kernel network driver?

The formal [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/uio-howto.html) stated that "The integer value read from /dev/uioX represents the total interrupt count".

2. Each interrupt represents a received/sent package?
   e.g. read() returns the number of newly packages received.
3. There is only one type interrupt?

The files are backed by HUGEPAGEs and shared with the NIC (by physical address).

4. If my process crashes, who frees them? how does the NIC knows to stop?

Comment: `Doesn't using read/write just generates more context switches?` "More context switches" then ... ? `Each interrupt represents a received/sent package?` It's an input/output system. Interrupt probably refers to a hardware interrupt as produced by some I/O card. Like rising edge.

Comment: more than using the kernel network driver, I'll fix it. And yes its a hardware interrupt but it has meaning (from what I understood it means a packet was sent/received).